# Trouble generating unique UUIDv4 at model instanciation

Tags: node.js, uuid, mongoose-schema

I am having an issue related to UUID when trying to create an instance of mongoose model.

## Mongoose Schema

```
export interface IRessourceModel extends IRessource, mongoose.Document { }

export let RessourceSchema: mongoose.Schema = new Schema({
    uuid: {
        type: String,
        default: uuidv4() },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: RessourceValidation.CONSTANTS.NAME_MIN_LENGTH,
        maxlength: RessourceValidation.CONSTANTS.NAME_MAX_LENGTH,
        trim: true,
        validate: {
            validator: RessourceValidation.name,
            message: '{VALUE} is not a valid name'}},
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: RessourceValidation.ENUM.TYPE,
        validate: {
            validator: RessourceValidation.type,
            message: '{VALUE} is not a valid type'}},
    uploaded: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now }
})

export const Ressource: mongoose.Model<IRessourceModel> = mongoose.model<IRessourceModel>('Ressource', RessourceSchema);
```

## Instanciation

```
const RessourceModel = mongoose.model('Ressource');
// Some code here...

let Ressource: any = new RessourceModel({
    name: req.body.name,
    type: req.body.type,
})

Ressource.save((err, ressource) => {
    if (err)
        return (APIResponse.jsonErrorAfterMongooseQuery(res, 'Cannot create ressource', err));
    APIResponse.json(res, ressource);
})
```

---

## Issue

When I'm sending a POST request on `/ressources/` which is using the piece of instanciation code above, the ressource is created but, if I send another POST request, the second ressource created has the same UUID than the first one...

#### Results for POST request #1

```
{
    "type": true,
    "data": {
        "uuid": "1794bbb4-3385-4b0d-909a-e22c60aee608",
        "_id": "5b3a42f5ae71a02af4ed6d11",
        "name": "Name of ressource 1",
        "type": "IMAGE",
        "uploaded": "2018-07-02T15:21:25.866Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

#### Results for POST request #2

```
{
    "type": true,
    "data": {
        "uuid": "1794bbb4-3385-4b0d-909a-e22c60aee608",
        "_id": "5b3a4530f3ab1f3d40b7ac93",
        "name": "Name of ressource 2",
        "type": "IMAGE",
        "uploaded": "2018-07-02T15:30:56.379Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Am I using the `default: uuidv4()` wrongly or is it coming from the way I instanciate the mongoose model ? Or anything else ?

I do have tried to set the UUID from the `Schema.pre('save')` function but without success...

I'm a bit lost, thanks for your help !

Comment: It isn't shown in the question what `uuidv4` is. If it's `require('uuidv4')`, this should be stated explicitly.

Comment: I have updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `uuidv4()` is a string. Of course, it will be same in all models.

Considering that:

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuidv4');
```

Mongoose [`default` schema option can accept a function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#default-functions) to generate a value:

```
export let RessourceSchema: mongoose.Schema = new Schema({
    uuid: {
        type: String,
        default: uuidv4
    },
    ...
```

Comment: I already try that but when I send a POST request to create the ressource, the uuid attribute is missing in the result of the request which means that the default function is not executed or something went wrong (and I don't have any error throwed)

Comment: Okey, it seems that i'm not importing the uuid package in the good way. I import it like that `import * as uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4';` which seems to be the problem here !

Comment: Glad it worked. Notice that you're already doing same thing here, `default: Date.now`.